# Unknown Column `comments_count`

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I'm having a weird problem with one of my models. I have a model `Podcast` that inherits from a base model `BCCFChildPage` that has `RatingField` and `CommentsField`.

Every other child model works except for `Podcast`. It's weird that it's only happening to one of my models and not to everything else.

Any input or comments would be great.

Thanks.

Models:

**Base Model:**

```
class BCCFChildPage(BCCFBasePage, RichText, AdminThumbMixin):
    """
    This is the page that shows up in the fancy carousels.
    """
    TYPES = (
        ('parent', 'Parents'),
        ('professional', 'Professionals'),
    )

    parent = models.ForeignKey('BCCFChildPage', blank=True, null=True)
    gparent = models.ForeignKey('BCCFPage', verbose_name="Parent Page", blank=True, null=True)
    bccf_topic = models.ManyToManyField('BCCFTopic', blank=True, null=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField('Featured', default=False)
    titles = models.CharField(editable=False, max_length=1000, null=True)
    content_model = models.CharField(editable=False, max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    rating = RatingField(verbose_name='Rating')
    comments = CommentsField()
    page_for = models.CharField('Type', max_length=13, default='parent', blank=True, null=True, choices=TYPES)
    image = FileField("Image",
        upload_to = upload_to("bccf.ChildPage.image_file", "childpage"),
        extensions = ['.png', '.jpg', '.bmp', '.gif'],
        max_length = 255,
        null = True,
        blank = True,
        help_text = 'You can upload an image. '
            'Acceptable file types: .png, .jpg, .bmp, .gif.')

    objects = managers.ChildPageManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'BCCF Child Page'
        verbose_name_plural = 'BCCF Child Pages'
        ordering = ("-created",)

    # Functions below...
```

**Child Model (Podcast):**

```
class Podcast(BCCFChildPage):
    attached_audio = FileField('Audio File',
       upload_to = upload_to("bccf.Podcast.attachment_audio", "resource/audio"),
        extensions = ['.mp3'],
        max_length = 1024,
        null = True,
        blank = True,
        help_text = 'You can upload an MP3. Acceptable file types: mp3')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name='Associated Product', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Podcast'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Podcasts'
```

**Error**

`(1054, "Unknown column 'bccf_podcast.comments_count' in 'field list'")`

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://bccf-staging.bjola.ca/admin/bccf/podcast/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('mezzanine.boot',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.redirects',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'ckeditor',
 'mezzanine.conf',
 'mezzanine.core',
 'mezzanine.generic',
 'mezzanine.forms',
 'mezzanine.pages',
 'mezzanine.twitter',
 'mezzanine.accounts',
 'news',
 'pybb',
 'bccf',
 'cartridge.shop',
 'formable.builder',
 'form_utils',
 'embed_video',
 'filebrowser_safe',
 'south',
 'grappelli_safe',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.comments')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'cartridge.shop.middleware.ShopMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.request.CurrentRequestMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForDeviceMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForHostMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.AdminLoginInterfaceSelectorMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.SitePermissionMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.pages.middleware.PageMiddleware',
 'pybb.middleware.PybbMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  432.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  198.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1395.             media = self.media + formset.media
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in media
  373.         if self.forms:
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  49.         res = instance.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in forms
  133.         forms = [self._construct_form(i) for i in xrange(self.total_form_count())]
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in total_form_count
  108.             initial_forms = self.initial_form_count()
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in initial_form_count
  550.             return len(self.get_queryset())
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  77.         self._fetch_all()
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  854.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  220.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  709.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  782.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  124.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  201.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/home/vcn/webapps/bccf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/bccf/podcast/
Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'bccf_podcast.comments_count' in 'field list'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Mezzanine? I'm very new to django but If you read mezzanine's documentation they advice you to only inherit from their Page (additionally with Richtext) and BlogPost classes. I found myself with this same trouble twice while adding translation capabilities and new custom post types. If your object doesn't fit any of those two classes, you can inherit from those models and inject any changes you desire: http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/model-customization.html

I think that's the mezzanine way..